# Can UIMenuController display each item in separate line?

Tags: ios, xcode, uimenucontroller

I have a UIImageController that its items are added in this way:
    `    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

```
NSString *selfMenuItemTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Self", @"Self");
UIMenuItem *selfMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:selfMenuItemTitle action:@selector(setPrivacySelf:)];

NSString *followersMenuItemTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Followers", @"Followers");
UIMenuItem *followersMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:followersMenuItemTitle action:@selector(setPrivacyFollower:)];

NSString *everyMenuItemTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"Everyone", @"Everyone");
UIMenuItem *everyMenuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:everyMenuItemTitle action:@selector(setPrivacyEvery:)];

[menuController setMenuItems:@[selfMenuItem,followersMenuItem,everyMenuItem]];

//CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
CGRect menuLocation = CGRectMake(200, 100,0 , 0);
[menuController setTargetRect:menuLocation inView:[self view]];

[menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];`
```

these items are shown horizontally in a line. how can I show each item in a separate line and create a vertical menu?
I found:https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu
and http://code4app.net/category/menu that has classes that made this kind of menus, Xcode has no default solution for this?

Comment: What have you tried? You have shown a piece of code but it doesn't relate to solving the problem. Please show an effort in code to solve the problem and where/why it isn't working.